# Is it possible to deprecate an Exception class?

Tags: python, exception

Situation: I have some custom Exception classes in my library, which is used by users in their code. For some reason, I want to rename one of the exceptions and deprecate the old one.

Keeping the old exception as an alias is not difficult:

```
class MyNewError(ValueError):
    pass

MyOldError = MyNewError
```

But eventually I would like to remove the old error name for my library, and therefore I want users who use this custom exception in downstream code to be notified with a DeprecationWarning that this error will be removed.

But I want to raise the DeprecationWarning in the following usecase (say that my library containing the custom exceptions is called `mypackage`):

```
# downstream user code
import mypackage

...

try:
    ....
except mypackage.MyOldError:
    ....
```

**So I want to raise the warning when the user tries to *catch* the error, not only when the user would *raise* the error.**

Is it possible to do this in some way? (as the user is not calling a function here in which I can raise a deprecation warning)

Comment: I don't think you can - you presumably don't want to raise a warning every time someone imports `mypackage`, and I don't think there's a sensible way to override `__getitem__` at the module level (see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/10438894/3001761 - it's awkward).

Answer (score 4):

You can apply the hack/trick from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2447383/6394138), converting your module into a class and intercepting the `__getattr__()` operation:

**mypackage/__init__.py**:

```
import sys
import warnings

class MyNewError(ValueError):
    pass

MyOldError = MyNewError

def foo():
    print('mypackage.foo(): raising MyNewError')
    raise MyNewError()

class Wrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, wrapped):
        self.wrapped = wrapped

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name == 'MyOldError':
            warnings.warn('MyOldError is deprecated, use MyNewError')

        return getattr(self.wrapped, name)

sys.modules[__name__] = Wrapper(sys.modules[__name__])
```

**test.py**:

```
import mypackage

try:
    mypackage.foo()
except mypackage.MyOldError:
    print('Caught mypackage.MyOldError')
```

**Output**:

```
$ python test.py 
mypackage.foo(): raising MyNewError
mypackage/__init__.py:18: UserWarning: MyOldError is deprecated, use MyNewError
  warnings.warn('MyOldError is deprecated, please use MyNewError')
Caught mypackage.MyOldError
```

Answer (score 2):

It's certainly possible to raise an exception within an exception, but if the user isn't expecting it, it could cause issues.  Assuming that was just a misstep in your post, and you don't have a `DeprecationWarning` exception you want to raise, you can do the following:

```
class MyOldError(MyNewError):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        deprecation_warning('Deprecated, please use MyNewError')

>>> raise MyOldError
Deprecated, please use MyNewError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
__main__.MyOldError
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks! This works for raising an error, but I would also like to show a deprecation warning in case someone tries to *catch* the error (see the example use case in my question)

Comment: Aah I see what you mean.  It would be possible to do this with [metaclasses and magic methods](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-instance-and-subclass-checks), but I'm not certain how useful that would be.  I'll think on an elegant solution in the meantime, but no promises.  Someone might beat me to it, too.