# In Python, when looking up an undefined global variable, is it possible to dynamically generate a value?

Tags: python-3.x, dynamic, global-variables, undefined, name-lookup

In Lua, global variables are stored in a table named `_G`.  You can add a metatable to `_G`, such that when you lookup an undefined global value, a user defined function is called to provide a value.

In the below example, looking up any undefined variable returns the name of the undefined variable.

```
setmetatable ( _G, { __index = function ( t, k ) return k end } )

print ( foo )    --  prints the string "foo"
foo  =  5
print ( foo )    --  prints 5
print ( bar )    --  prints the string "bar"
```

Is it possible to achieve the same effect in Python 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated answer from Dec 12, 2018:**

Here is another (better?) way.  Basically, we manually `read()`, `compile()`, and then `exec()` the entire source file.  When we call `exec()`, we can pass in an alternative global dictionary.  The entire file is read, compiled, and executed twice, but we do achieve the desired result.

```
def  baz  ():
  global  foo
  print ( foo )    #  should print the string 'foo'                             
  foo  =  5
  print ( foo )    #  should print 5                                            
  print ( bar )    #  should print the string 'bar'                             


class  CustomGlobals ( dict ):
  def  __getitem__  ( self, k ):
    if  k in self:  return  self .get ( k )
    if  hasattr ( self .get ( '__builtins__' ), k ):
      #  we raise KeyError to avoid clobbering builtins                         
      raise  KeyError
    return  k


def  main  ():

  with  open ( __file__, 'rb' ) as f:
    source  =  f .read()    # re-read __file__                                  
  code  =  compile ( source, __file__, 'exec' )    #  re-compile __file__       

  g  =  CustomGlobals ( globals() )
  g [ '__name__' ]  =  None    #  prevent infinite recursion                    
  exec ( code, g )    #  re-exec __file__ against g                             

  g [ 'baz' ] ()    #  call the re-complied baz function                        

if  __name__ == '__main__':  main()
```

The above approach is superior (IMO) because we do not need to nest code in a string, and because error messages will contain correct line numbers.

**Original answer from Nov 29, 2018:**

If the Python code in question comes from a string (rather than a standard `.py` file), then you can `exec()` the string and provide a custom global dictionary as follows:

```
code  =  '''                                                                     
print ( foo )    #  should print the string 'foo'                               
foo  =  5                                                                       
print ( foo )    #  should print 5                                              
print ( bar )    #  should print the string 'bar'                               
'''

class  CustomDict ( dict ):
  def  __init__  ( self, other ):  super() .__init__ ( other )
  def  __getitem__  ( self, k ):
    if  k in self:  return  self .get ( k )
    if  hasattr ( self .get ( '__builtins__' ), k ):
      #  we raise KeyError to avoid clobbering builtins 
      raise  KeyError
    return  k

exec ( code, None, CustomDict ( globals() ) )
```

As desired, the above outputs:

```
foo
5
bar
```

I have not found any way to "mutate" a module to achieve the same result for code that is in that module.  If anyone knows of a way to mutate a module, I would be very happy to see it.

(Perhaps a module could read its own source code into a string, then compile that string in the context of a custom global `dict`, and then inject the result into `sys.modules`?  In other words, the module would replace itself with a clone of itself, but with a different global `dict`.  Hmmm.)

Aside: There are ways to simulate `__getitem__()` and `__getattr__()` on a module.  And as of Python 3.7, you can simply and directly define a `__getattr__()` function in the module.  However, as far as I can tell, none of these techniques can hook into the lookup of global variables.  Sources:

- [Python 3 documentation for `exec()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec)
- [Python: subscript a module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10439002)
- [__getattr__ on a module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48916205)
- [PEP 562 -- Module __getattr__ and __dir__](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0562/)

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean something like

```
print(bar) if 'bar' in globals() else print('bar')
```

Comment: Yes, but I want it systematized so that all I have to write is `print(bar)` and the rest happens automatically (as in the Lua example I provided).  I suspect that if I could install a `__getitem__()` method of the `globals()` dictionary, that might work.  But I don't know if that is possible in Python.